# Deferring size calculations until ui rendered

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my markup:

```
<div resizer>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b">
        This content generated dynamically using ng-include and other directives inside
    </div>
</div>
```

The second div (`.b`) changes it's height (elements added inside it dynamically). I wrote a directive that should update the first div (`.a`)according to the available height:

```
'use strict';
myModule.directive('resizer', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function updateSizes(event) {
                var a = element.find('.a');
                var b = element.find('.b');

                var bHeight = b.outerHeight();
                var totalHeight = element.height();
                a.height(totalHeight - bHeight);
            }

            element.on('some-event', updateSizes);
            $timeout(updateSizes);
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I start my app, sometimes, my divs get height equal to zero (height: 0) because b.outerHeight(); and element.height(); return zero.
Why is that? I used $timeout so the browser has time to render the views.
Any idea?

Comment: **The Angular Way** is a common and good question. AngularJS has a natural flow where the changing model redefines the content or styles. So usually, "The Angular Way" for something like changing content, is simply the HTML way. It seems as though you want to size your divs to fit content. But, if I understand you correctly, you are doing too much work. Divs are inherently meant to resize to content. So, unless you assign fix height or width to the div, it should behave as you like. If you want extra behavior (padding, centering, fixed width), this would be more of CSS answer than "Angular".

Comment: this should be done by css instead.

Comment: @DaveA This couldn't be done using CSS because I need the sizes to be updated in also runtime. I'll update my code - there is also binding to an event which cause a size update. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Naor, still unclear. I'm missing something big. In my mind, Divs automatically resize to their contents. And as I've model-bound data or content, and changed it (or changed the directive to use a different template), my div has resized. Less than meaning CSS is your answer, I miss why the div needs any resizing -- ergo, change the content with a scope variable or the style with ng-style directive and the div should change accordingly. As often happens in misunderstandings of this type, I probably am missing a part of your functional goal.

Comment: better than a code update (useful) would be a fiddle and an explanation of what it fails to do and what needs to be changed!

Comment: @DaveA I'll try to create a jsFiddle that will recreate this error. But I'll do it later. I'll try to explain again. I have two divs and the bottom one always changes it's height by adding elements. The purpose of my resizer directive is to calculate the free space available after the height changes and update the first div height.

Comment: @Naor, if I understand right, after your inner div resizes, the outer div has extra space left. That's interesting. I'd expect the outer div to collapse with the inner. unless it had a fixed height. But I don't see that in your example. Is it in CSS? Does **class a** have a height component?

Comment: I would like to chime in in saying that CSS probably is the way to go here. For a correct solution I would need a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve, though. As it stands, div.a looks completely useless to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach

A common pattern with angular is to have a nested directive *require* a parent directive and register itself with the parent. You can use this pattern to solve your problem. I've added the nested directives **resizer-source** and **resizer-dest** to your markup:

```
<div resizer>
    <div class="a" resizer-dest></div>
    <div class="b" resizer-source>
        This content generated dynamically using ng-include and other directives inside
    </div>
</div>
```

### resizer-source

```
myModule.directive('resizerSource', function () {
    return {
        require: '^resizer',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.registerSource(element);
        }
    };
});
```

### resizer-dest

```
myModule.directive('resizerDest', function () {
    return {
        require: '^resizer',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.registerDest(element);
        }
    };
});
```

### resizer

```
myModule.directive('resizer', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            var a,b;
            function update() {
              if (a && b) {
                var bHeight = b.outerHeight();
                var totalHeight = element.height();
                a.height(totalHeight - bHeight);
              }
            }
            this.registerSource = function(elm) {
                b = elm;
                update();
            }
            this.registerDest = function(elm) {
                a = elm;
                update();
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

### Even More Flexibility

If for some reason the height of **b** isn't available even by the time **b**'s link function runs, you can make this even more flexible by setting a `$watch` on **b**'s height and registering **b** only when the watch evaluates to a positive number. Afterwards, cancel the watcher unless you expect the element's height to continue changing.

## Additional Info

> if I'll $watch b's size, I'll have to cause a digest cycle (by calling $apply() or $digest). I am informing resizer to update using dom events. What do you think about that?

(1) `$watch`ing the size is an expensive operation because it will force a reflow every time you check the height. So cancel the `$watch` asap. (2) There is no guarantee that angular will trigger a digest cycle at the right time so using dom events as you've mentioned may be necessary.

For these reasons using a `$watch` may not be the best approach at all but it really depends on your particular situation.

> Isn't it a good practice to use the elements inside a link function?

There's nothing un-angular about using the controller instead of the link function. They have different orders of invocation, but that doesn't come into play here.

> you don't have an access to 'element' in the controller.. Is putting the resizer code inside the link function safe? I mean, I have to put registerSource and registerDest on the controller

You can inject `$element` into the controller if you need it. Alternatively, you can add a directive's own controller to the `require` property to access it from the `link` function. Whether you choose to put code in the controller or `link` function will usually come down to organization, so don't be afraid to use the controller instead of the `link` function if it simplifies your code.

Comment: Sounds like the correct approach. I'll try that. Regarding to your suggestion about the $watch, if I'll $watch b's size, I'll have to cause a digest cycle (by calling $apply() or $digest). I am informing resizer to update using dom events. What do you think about that?

Comment: Another question, you used the 'a' and 'b' elements on the resizer controller. Is it valid? Isn't it a good practice to use the elements inside a link function?

Comment: In addition, you don't have an access to 'element' in the controller.. Is putting the resizer code inside the link function safe? I mean, I have to put registerSource and registerDest on the controller...

Comment: I've added a section to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible options (see [ngInclude docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)):

1. use ngInclude onload event
2. listen to the $includeContentLoaded event emitted by ngInclude when the content is loaded

I would suggest to use the second option, since will save you to specify the onload event everytime you want to use your directive.
You can specify the listener inside your link function like this:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(){
        console.log('Template included');
        // you can add all your height calculation and DOM manipulation here
    });
}
```

Have a look at [this demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nKuqcUrlY659AUqTmix?p=preview) (I hope the content is quite self-explanatory).
Your code should indeed look like this:

```
'use strict';
myModule.directive('resizer', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function updateSizes(event) {
                var a = element.find('.a');
                var b = element.find('.b');

                var bHeight = b.outerHeight();
                var totalHeight = element.height();
                a.height(totalHeight - bHeight);
            }

            scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', updateSizes);

        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that updateSizes() called many times (the times I have ng-include somewhere in the current route). I added a counter and this method happened more then 20 times.

Comment: Well, if you have 20 directives it will be called 20 times of course. If you have some particular logic to follow (you want to resize just certain elements), you could add an option to your directive to add the listener. I would suggest you to put some other code to display the behavior (a plunker would be even better).

Comment: If you have nested directives, you can add stopPropagation to prevent the parent directive to listen to the children event.

Comment: But still, updateSizes() will be called more then once (according to the number of inner ng-includes)

Comment: At this point you have different solutions: [this post](http://competa.com/blog/2013/12/how-to-detect-when-all-your-nested-ng-includes-have-loaded-their-content-in-angularjs/) suggests a way to fire an event when all includes have been loaded. Another option could be to add an attribute to your directive and conditionally do your work just on the includes you need. You could otherwise add/remove a class to elements that have already been checked or unbind the listener when the include is fired. I am not able to suggest you the best one without seeing your nested code. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be having an `ng-include` in your directives template.

`ng-include` is itself a directive and its creating a new scope. Your `resizer` directives `link` function however is executed as soon as the HTML is rendered, so the `ng-include`-d template is already there, but its content is not yet loaded (its even a seperate **HTTP/GET** request if the template was not loaded before).

I'm sure there are more fixes, but one would be to use the `onload` parameter of the `ng-include` tag:

```
// ... your directive ...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  function updateSizes(event) {
    console.log (element.find('.b').outerHeight());
  }

  scope.ngOnload = updateSizes;
}
```

So now into your html template:

```
<div resizer>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b">
    <div ng-include="'sometemplate.html'" onload="ngOnload()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This did the trick for me and the `div.b` elements outerHeight was not 0 anymore in the console log.

---

*I see, that you've played around with `$timeout` to wait for the browser. If my solution does not work for you, there must be something weird loaded in those `div`, probably more details needed for a solution. However a `debugger` statement with chrome debugger in the `updateSizes` function could help a lot.*

Comment: This is sound logical, but the thing is that I have several nested ng-includes. Where should I put the onload? Should I wait until the whole dom will be rendered? How?

Comment: @Naor Well thats another question, the solution really depends what you want to achieve not only from user standpoint, but from code infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue may be caused by the delay in loading the ng-include resources.  You can pre-load the cache:

```
$templateCache.put('template.html', '<b>Template</b>');
```

Or if the contents are from an $http call:

```
$http.get('template.html', {cache:$templateCache});
```

Comment: There are many reasons for the delay. Template loading, template rendering, digest cycle and so on. I am looking for a way to do something when the rendering is over. You try to avoid the delay but this is unavoidable.

Comment: Right but because of the asynchronous nature of angular to load templates, coupled with the fact that you need the DOM to be fully rendered, may mean that you need to preload the templates (and also using $timeout) as part of your solution

Comment: Let me tell you that I am concatenating all my templates in one big js file with $templateCache and this script concatenated with the application js. So there is no $http request here. Still, I have a delay.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer that you are looking for, but why do you go so far to make that simple things to work?

`The best programming is, no programming`

I would just recommend you css only solution for this purpose

```
<style>
.tbl {display:table}
.tbl-row {display:table-row}
.tbl-cell {display:table-cell}
</style>

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="tbl-row">
    <div class="tbl-cell">Foo</div>
    <div class="tbl-cell">
        This content generated dynamically using ng-include and other directives inside
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/H81p2yu0jG8OuB8paFpM?p=preview

Comment: Did you check it? this code produces two divs in one row instead two rows.

Comment: I thought this wasn't worth plnkr. I added one

Comment: I just realized it wasn't so clear in my question. The two divs are one on top of the other and not one right of the other. Two rows and not two cells. This is why I am changing the height and not the width.